# pyinstaller -- No Module Named pyWinhook

Tags: pyinstaller

Tried removing the part that used pyWinhook from the project, and I got it running.
Anyone know how to fix it ?
Tried hidden import, but did not help..

File "ScreenShot.py", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyWinhook'

Problem was to do with Swig files, downloaded the swig files and copied it to the python source folders.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install that module using

```
pip install pyWinhook
```